# No me funciona el select count

Tags: group-by

Debo contar la cantidad de libros que tiene un autor (la cantidad de libros es de 18, y los autores son 25)

```
SELECT autor_id,titulo,COUNT(*) as cantidad_libros
FROM titulo_autor ta,titulos ti
WHERE ta.titulo_id = ti.titulo_id
GROUP BY ta.autor_id, titulo
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, ya que me cuenta solo 1 por cada titulo e incluso se repiten muchos valores

Comment: Agrega la estructura de las tablas por favor

Comment: "contar la cantidad de libros que tiene un autor", no es lo que hace esta consulta, quita la columna titulo del `select` y del `group by`, creo que esa sería la idea.

Comment: gracias! pero debo mostrar tambien los titulos

Comment: Aparte de lo que ya te mencionan deberías usar una sintaxis de `JOIN` explícita para la relación que existe entre tus 2 entidades

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos estás usando?

Comment: El tipo de resultados que quieres obtener es raro: por un lado quieres el total de libros de un autor, pero al mismo tiempo quieres los títulos de esos libros. No es que sean dos cosas incompatibles, pero es posible que haya un error de enfoque en la lógica de tu programa. O requieres una cosa: el total de libros del autor, o requieres otra, el titulo del libro. Otra cosa es que se requiera un informe sobre autores y títulos con ciertas palabras o con títulos tratando sobre ciertos temas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo que logro ver es que tu FK esta mal definida tienes en la tabla titulo autor una FK apuntando a titulo lo que implica que por cada autor tendrás solo un registro por libro cuando esa FK debería estar en títulos y de títulos apuntando a autores ya que 1 autor tiene 1 o muchos títulos 1:n y además en títulos deberías agregar un campo existencia para no tener que duplicar registros cada vez que ingresas un nuevo libro.
[image: introducir la descripcón de la imagen aquí]

Supongamos que tenemos una tabla autores con el siguiente contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y una tabla de títulos con el siguiente contenido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera para retornar un listado con la existencia bastaría con hacer un select a la tabla títulos y si deseas agregar el autor bastaría con un sencillo JOIN.

```
SELECT
   a.nombre AS autor , t.nombre AS titulo , existencia
FROM
    titulos t
        LEFT JOIN
    autores a ON a.idautores = t.autor_idautor;
```

Ahora si lo que deseas es un conteo de todos los libros que tiene un autor en la tabla de títulos solo deberás contar las existencias mediante un SUM():

```
SELECT
  a.nombre, SUM(existencia) AS total
FROM
titulos t
    LEFT JOIN
autores a ON a.idautores = t.autor_idautor
GROUP BY autor_idautor;
```

**Aclaracion count(*) y diferencia con SUM()**

Vale la pena recordar que count() cuenta solo los registros que cumplen la condición solicitada o sea solo suma la unicidad del registro, SUM() por otro lado es un acumulador de la columna solicitada, así que para nuestro caso sirve.

Saludos.